# Image not getting displayed inside webview in Android 3.0?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using the following code to display an image of more than 1,000x1,000, stored in the assets folder of my project. To enable zoom controls on it, I want to display it in a WebView.

My code:

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
  String html_data;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    loadHTML();
  }
  public void loadHTML() {
    final String mimeType = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "utf-8";
    final String html = "<h1>Header</h1><p>Custom HTML</p><p><img src=\\"
      + "file:///android_asset/africa.png\\/></p>";
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", html, mimeType, encoding,"");
  }
}
```

And my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView
  android:id="@+id/mapview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the path of the image to:

```
String html = "<h1>Header</h1><p>Custom HTML</p><p><img src=\"file:///android_asset/africa.png\"/></p>";
```

And pls make sure that you have africa.png under your projects asset folder.

Comment: It seems that the image is loading but not getting displayed, as i can see the scroll bars of the Web view on emulator.

Comment: there is no problem with the code,try it by the default image of android that is ic_launcher.png.if the image gets displayed than there is must be some issue of image.

Comment: I guess the problem lies in my images, ic_launcher is loading properly. Thanks